# Hbase shell giving loadError

Tags: hadoop, hbase

dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase-1.2.5/bin$ **start-hbase.sh**

it shows below

```
localhost: zookeeper running as process 6637. Stop it first.
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.2.5/logs/hbase-dinesh-master-dinesh-VirtualBox.out
starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.2.5/logs/hbase-dinesh-1-regionserver-dinesh-VirtualBox.out
```

but 
dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase-1.2.5/bin$ **hbase shell**

```
LoadError: load error: hbase -- java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make member of class 
sun.nio.cs.Unicode accessible:  module java.base does not export 
sun.nio.cs to unnamed module @5befbac1
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1062
(root) at /usr/local/hbase-1.2.5/bin/hirb.rb:118
```

hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

In **hbase-env.sh** I added below line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
```

In .bashrc file, added below lines

```
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase-1.2.5 
export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_HOME/bin
```

don't know where the problem is, anyone knows solution of this, then please post here. Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
First stop hbase using command **./bin/stop-hbase.sh**
If the zookeeper process is still running, kill it. (kill -9 process_id)


You have configured hbase to run in **distributed mode** yet 'localhost' is used in the hbase.rootdir. 
I would expect to see something like hdfs://xx.xx.xx.xx:54310/hbase.

Have you added the conf/regionservers file which lists all your regionservers ? This is mandatory if hbase is run in distributed mode.

In hbase-env.sh add the folLowing line
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true, if you are not managing the zookeeper daemon
```

Add THE FOLLOWING TWO PROPERTIES IN HBASE-SITE.XML

```
  <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
      </description>
  </property>
  <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>HOSTS_WHERE_ZOOKEEPER_IS_RUNNING</value>
   </property>

The hbase.zookeeper.quorum property is a comma-separated list of hosts on which ZooKeeper servers are running.



HBase logs can be found in the logs subdirectory. Check them out if you still have trouble starting hbase
```